# Old iPads and data pull automation

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, automator, python

I have 20 old iPads (mini 5th gen, software version 12.2) that are used for note taking daily.  The application, Tap Forms HD has a export folder that holds a .csv file. The .csv file is still stored on Tap Forms. For security reasons the iPads can not be connected to WiFi. Currently each .csv file has to be manually transferred to the hard drive via usb. Is there software that can automate this process so that once a iPad is plugged in, the .csv file is pulled from the iPad and copied to the Mac hard drive?

I can also code python but I do not have any experience with coding on a Mac. A small python script could work.

Comment: What do you mean by "old", which version of iOS are they running? Also, which note taking app is used, and what does it offer in terms of cloud integration?

Comment: Added detail to post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, but it doesn’t really help add context to what you’ve done so far that hasn’t worked. Can you explain why iTunes/Finder sync doesn’t meet your needs?